# How to install a ROM in a MTK phone via FLASHTOOL

Tags: rom, flashtool

I have already tried to install a ROM in a chinese phone with the MTK 6582 processor (1,3 GHz). And I have tried with others processors like MTK 6589. When I connect the phone at the PC, FLASHTOOL doesn`t detect the phone. What could be the reason? If there was another posibility to install a ROM in a chinese phone I would like to know it (I have tried with CWM). I use windows 8, but I would prefer to use Ubuntu.
I would like to know all the steps to install a ROM via FLASHTOOL, because i dont know the step in  which I failed.
The phone I used is Mlais MX28.

Comment: Is this an Android phone?  Make and model will help.

Comment: The model is Mlais Mx28, I have submitted the model at the question.

Comment: Which ROM are you trying to flash? Do you have CWM already installed on the phone? What's this FLASHTOOL utility you keep mentioning? Do you have USB drivers for the phone installed on your Windows machine?

Comment: This is the ROM I need to flash with flashtool [link](http://www.needrom.com/mobile/mlais-mx28/) _italic_ **bold** `code` . I have already flashed a ROM with CWM, but when I did it, the phone lost the touchscreen funcionality, that`s why I want do it via flashtool. The problem is when I connect the phone by USB and I press "download", nothing happen. I think I have already drivers installed, because I have downloaded mtk 6582 drivers, How could I know it?

Comment: Don't connect your phone yet, press Download first. Then connect your phone without a battery, then after a few seconds insert the battery. SPFT should see your phone. Switch USB ports if necessary

Comment: @Sergiohernandez Did your device already have a CWM recovery installed, or did you install it via the CWM app? Mine came with a pretty much useless Chinese recovery (besides being unreadable, it automatically exits within 15-20 seconds of entering recovery mode) and I cannot find a suitable recovery to be flashed via the CWM app (since the phone is not listed in the official CWM recoveries list).